# How to make a request in Node.js with backslashes in the path?

Tags: node.js, url, request

I'm using the `request` npm module to access a REST service, that needs at some point requires a backslash (`\`) in part of the path to escape a especial character (it implements a small query DSL).

To my surprise, request is converting those backslashes to forward slashes (`/`). I've drilled down the problem a little bit more and it seems that it is calling `url.parse` under the hood and that is the culprit. I can pass a `url.parse` result with the proper path, but I don't see any option to avoid the back to forward slash conversion.

The ugly option might be to hack the `url.parse` result myself...

Comment: Have you tried encoding the backslash (as `%5C`)?

Comment: not yet, I'm on it...

Comment: yeah, that works on the nodejs side, it doesn't try to replace it, let's see if the REST API likes it as well :)

Comment: Cool, that's probably it (also, here's my go-to de/encoder: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/).

Comment: @admdrew It worked, do you want to write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to [encode](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) the backslashes (`%5C`) so that node.js knows they're not part of the URL itself.

Comment: So does it mean basically before calling to the url.parse we need to encode the URL in UTF-8 format?

Comment: That seems right, but I am not sure. This answer is very old!